# Using JaxWsProxyFactoryBean and Spring how do I make an HTTPS connection through a proxy?

Tags: spring-boot, cxf

I am trying to use JaxWsProxyFactoryBean to connect to a TLS1.2 https service using spring boot and java config through a proxy.  I have been unable to find any samples, or information about how to configure this.  Im using wsdl2java to build all of the objects that eventually get returned from JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  What I currently have:

```
 private <T> T cxfClient(String address, String user, String pass, Class<T> serviceClass) {     
    JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
    factory.setAddress(address);
    factory.setUsername(user);
    factory.setPassword(pass);


    return factory.create(serviceClass);
}
```

and

```
@Bean
public Client client() {    
    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(lexisNexisClient());
    HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
    http.getClient().setProxyServer("myproxy");
    http.getClient().setProxyServerPort(myport);
    http.getProxyAuthorization().setUserName("myuser");
    http.getProxyAuthorization().setPassword("mypass");
    return client;
}
```

I am currently getting an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSClientParameters.getSslContext()Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLContext
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue ended up being a dependency problem with CXF versions.  Apparently the Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLContext means there is a dependency version conflict.

Thanks,
Brian